# diophantine system

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following system. All variables are integers with $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

\begin{cases} a_1^2+b_1^2= 2p^2 +2pq+q^2\\ a_2^2+b_2^2=p^2+q^2 \\a_1a_2+b_1b_2=p^2+2pq \end{cases}

It is easy to see that this system has solutions $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2)=(p, p+q, q,p) \, \text{and}\,\,(p+q,p,p,q)$.

The question is whether there exist values of $p$ and $q$ such that there are other solutions as well.

For example, if one chooses $p=2591$ and $q=7567$ then besides the easy solution

$(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2)=(2591, 10158, 7567, 2591)$ we have another (essentially different) solution:

$(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2)=(9681, 4022, 6613, -4499)$.

In this case however we have  $\gcd(p^2+q^2, p^2+2pq)=\gcd(63972770, 45925475)=5$.

The question is whether there exist values of $p$ and $q$ such that the above system has at least two distinct solutions (up to permutations of the entries) **and** $\gcd(p^2+q^2, p^2+2pq)=1$.

I do not know if I am missing some impossibility modulo 5 argument or I simply did not search long enough.

Answer (score 1):

My first impression is that there will be a gcd regardless, because you have a rational rotation, in your case take either vector (a,b) as a column and multiply by
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{3}{5 }  & \frac{4}{5} \\
-\frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which is based on the Pythagorean triple $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$

If a 2 by 2 matrix is special orthogonal and rational, it is one of these, made from a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: I do not quite get your idea; can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ Will Jagy. I understand that if $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2)$ is an (integer) solution, then so is $(3a_1+4b_1, -4a_1+3b_1, 3a_2+4b_2, -4a_2+3b_2)/5$ - rational solution this time.  But how does this exclude the possibility of the integer solution in the first place?

Comment: @user84909 I don't think it finishes the problem. What is true is that you are asking for a triangle that is congruent to the original one you get for free, in such a position that it must be a rotation (since you also get a reflected version for free), and everything is integers so it must be a rational matrix. It is not clear to me how far this idea goes; for example, I was unable to find any examples where the matrix constructed from the (5,12,13) Pythagorean triangle works.